# Hadoop map method with or without "implements"?

Tags: hadoop

In some books (such as Hadoop, The Definitive Guide) the Mapper method is defined like this:

> public class MapClass extends Mapper extends Mapper<...

but in other books (such as Hadoop in Action) is like this:

> public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper
>   <...

Which one is prefered or what's the difference?.

Maybe the first option is newer?.

Why static?.

Regards

Comment: `static` is because it is declared as an inner class of something else. This isn't required, and I don't even think it's good design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mapper`s and `Reducer`s were interfaces in the old API, but are now classes that tasks inherit from. Implementations from both the old and new API show up in transitional Hadoop distributions, but if you don't have legacy code that depends on the old stuff, you should stick to the new API. The two are not in general interoperable.

Comment: OK, thanks. The problem is that I'm reading (or browsing) several books and things have changed too quickly.

Comment: Yes, it can be difficult to keep track of things. Most of the old classes fall under the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` hierarchy, while the new ones fall under `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce`. As long as you're using the latter namespace, you'll usually be fine.